# the cop (who's) escorting him

Tags: present-participles, reduced-relative-clauses

> One of the cops escorts Tim out of the house and toward a police car. Curious neighbors have gathered outside. **Tim spits on the cop (who's) escorting him**.

1. Is "escorts" the more natural choice of verb to use in this context?
2. Is the emboldened sentence phrased naturally without adding "who's"?

Comment: What do you think? What are your doubts? How many cops does Tim spit at/on? You should be able to work this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

"Escort" is a good verb to use:

> To accompany (a person) in order to compel them to go somewhere (e.g. to leave a building).

There are two ways to create a modifying phrase: you can use a particple phrase "the  cop *escorting him*" or a relative clause "the cop *who is escorting him*"  both are possible, it is up to you which one to choose.

The tense of the story is rather unusual. It is written as if a person is recording what they see *as they see it*.  It would be be less marked to use the past tense:  "One of the cops escorted Tim....".  You may also want to change the focus to Tim "Tim was escorted ... by one one of the cops"