# Are all three sentences OK?

Tags: sentence-choice

> One of the cops escorts Tim out of the house and toward a police car. Curious neighbors have gathered outside. **Tim spits on the cop escorting him. (1)** - **Tim spits on the cop who's escorting him. (2)** - **Tim spits on the escorting cop. (3)**

Are the three suggested sentences all OK or are some of them awkward-sounding?

Comment: Very similar to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278160/the-cop-whos-escorting-him One wonders why you are writing a story in English if you are so unsure of your own language skills. FWIW, I prefer (1) and don't like (3).

Comment: You are simply providing options and asking the community to pick the best one.

Comment: I'd agree with Kate.  The other odd thing is the use of a present tense narrative. This has a dramatic effect. Stories are normally told in the past tense, you need a reason to use the present.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions repeatedly (in this case, more than a few times) using different accounts.